# How to compare multiple keys value in same JSON file using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a sample JSON file:

```
"client_info": [
        {
            "Id": "00201",
            "Information": {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 12
            },
            "Address": [
                {         
                    "country": USA,
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "ad1": "NY"                          
                        },
                        {
                            "ad1": "FL"                          
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "00202",
            "Information": {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 13
            },
            "Address": [
                { 
                    "country": CA,
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "ad1": "NY"                          
                        },
                        {
                            "ad1": "FL"                          
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
{
            "Id": "00203",
            "Information": {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 13
            },
            "Address": [
                {
                    "country": CA,
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "ad1": "NY"                          
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Here I need to compare Information.Name ,Location.ad1 together for each entry. For example: ID 00201 - John, NY, FL is equal with ID 00202 but ID 00203 is different as it has only "ad1": "NY" . Basically need to compare as a set.
I can create the CSV file but my problem is to make that matched result set. I tried the below code to create matched result set but wasnot able to populate the set correcrtly:

```
uniqueNameSet = set()
uniquelocationSet = set()
        for i,client in enumerate(json_data["client_info"]):
            if client["Information"]['Name'] not in uniqueNameSet :
                uniqueNameSet.add(client["Information"]['Name'])        
            else:
                for j in range(len(client["Address"][0]['location'])):
                    if client["Address"][0]['location'][j]['ad1'] not in uniquelocationSet : 
                        uniquelocationSet.add(client["Address"][0]['location'][j]['ad1'])        
                    else: 
                        duplictae +=1
```

I want to generate a CSV for the matched data and removed those from the JSON file.
matched.csv

```
id     Name    ad1
00201  John  NY,FL
00202  John  NY,FL
```

updated Json file:

```
"client_info": [
{
            "Id": "00203",
            "Information": {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 13
            },
            "Address": [
                {
                    "country": CA,
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "ad1": "NY"                          
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question.

Comment: I assume `uniqueTitleSet` should be `uniqueNameSet`?

Comment: yes,,sorry my bad

Comment: the code you have provided does not attempt to generate anything like what you desire, how is it not giving you what you want? if the answer is anything other than "it's not making a CSV" then you need a bit more detail, and if it is just about making the CSV then you haven't done enough research,

Comment: Hi, my code is not creating the proper matched set! I am struggling to get the matched result set

Comment: if i were you i would use an encoded .txt file instead of json, json doesn't work as well as json does with javascript